# Use pair of objects as key, pass them to their property's constructor, without a hashing layer

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

How can I meet all of these requirements?

1. eliminate the extra level of nesting
2. eliminate the required constructor params node0 and node1
3. use valid Javascript
4. prioritize ease of use (**no custom hashing function**)

---

**BAD**

```
let interactions = {
    node0: {
        node1: {
            physics: new PhysicsReducer(node0, node1, config);
        }
    }
};
```

**GOOD**

```
let interactions = {
    [node0, node1]: {
        physics: new PhysicsReducer(config)
    }
};
```

---

Thanks

Comment: Great. Is there a question?

Comment: @RobG the question is -- how can I meet all of these requirements

Comment: So are you proposing a new syntax (and hence will need a parser & compiler) or are you asking how to do this in plain JS using spread/rest elements?

Comment: @RobG requirement #3 use valid Javascript, yes something like spread or `new Map().set(hash(obj,obj2), reducer)`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use plain objects as object keys in JS without hashing. Period. You need to weaken the requirements.